# "As far as job is concerned, marriage is no longer an obstacle." Is this a grammatically correct and meaningful sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

There was a question in a book:

> Do women in your country work after they get married?

Does "*As far as job is concerned, marriage is no longer an obstacle.*"

mean that having a job is no longer married life threatening for women?

Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: The sentence makes sense to me. It means that the marrige cannot be considered as an obstacle for employement.

Comment: I would use professional carrier instead of job. Also I would use it in plural form.

Comment: @Mabedan Did you perhaps mean ' professional career'?

Comment: haha nice mistake to make in an English language forum! probably the French "carrière" misled me

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not quite correct grammatically. If you were to use 'job' you would at least need to expand it into 'a job', but better 'holding/having a job'. But there are more succinct ways of asking the same question, such as:

'Marriage no longer presents an obstacle to working for a living'.

And I assume you mean this to apply to women only, so you may wish to add 'for women'.

Sadly,I always thought, in the case of men, marriage never ruled out working!

Comment: without saying "a job", it's not clear from the sentence itself that we are not discussing the prophet Job (or someone similarly named) with improper capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called a dangling modifier. Although it is decipherable, it is not grammatically correct.

The phrase `As far as a job is concerned` is next to the word `marriage` and far away from the word `obstacle`, which is (what the reader might assume) to be describing. To fix this sentence, simple transpose the two parts of the sentence:

*Marriage is no longer an obstacle as far as a job is concerned.*